# Uncaught You must specify a key using Parse.initialize

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, deployment, sdk

I've been using Parse for about three months but have started a new app. I am using Parse 1.4.2 js sdk.

I have some code in a separate file which is making a request to the database. The file is included in the main.js file.

When I try to deploy (using 1.4.2 sdk) I am getting the error:

```
Uploading source files
Uploading recent changes to scripts...
The following files will be uploaded:
/Users/aaron/dev/Familiar/cloud/main.js
/Users/aaron/dev/Familiar/cloud/user.js
/Users/aaron/dev/Familiar/cloud/verification.js
Finished uploading files
Uncaught You must specify a key using Parse.initialize.
```

If I try to deploy using the latest sdk, I get the error:

```
Uploading source files
Uploading recent changes to scripts...
The following files will be uploaded:
/Users/aaron/dev/Familiar/cloud/verification.js
Finished uploading files
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'request'
    at Object.ajaxMod [as ajax] (<anonymous>:925:19)
    at e.<anonymous> (Parse.js:13:25717)
    at e.s (Parse.js:12:26759)
    at Parse.js:12:27145
    at i (Parse.js:12:27100)
    at e.n.value (Parse.js:12:27130)
    at Object.y.request (Parse.js:13:25644)
    at Object.u.default.setQueryController.find (Parse.js:13:6132)
    at e.a.value (Parse.js:13:76)
    at e.<anonymous> (verification.js:18:38)
```

If I comment out all of `verification.js` it will upload, but with it uncommented I get the error. My other working app never calls `Parse.initialize`. Why is it asking for it now?

Directory structure:

```
├── cloud
│   ├── comment.js
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── config.js
│   │   ├── helpers.js
│   │   └── md5.js
│   ├── main.js
│   ├── user.js
│   └── verification.js
├── config
│   └── global.json
└── public
    └── index.html
```

**main.js**

```
require("cloud/user.js");
require("cloud/comment.js");
require("cloud/verification.js");
```

**verification.js**

```
var conf = require("cloud/lib/config.js").conf;
var helpers = require("cloud/lib/helpers.js");

function createSmsVerification(user) {
    return getUserSmsVerification(user)
        .then(function (verification) {
            var verificationQuery = new Parse.Query("Verification");
            return verificationQuery.first(); <-- this is the line causing the error
        })
        .then(function (verification) {
            return verification;
        }, function (error) {
            return Parse.Promise.error("createSmsVerification - " + error.message);
        });
}
exports.createSmsVerification = createSmsVerification();

function getUserSmsVerification(user) {
    return Parse.Promise.as();
}
```

**user.js**

```
var helpers         = require("cloud/lib/helpers.js"),
    conf            = require("cloud/lib/config.js").conf,
    sms             = require("cloud/sms.js"),
    verification    = require("cloud/verification.js");


Parse.Cloud.define("register", function(request, response){
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var phoneNumber = request.params.phoneNumber;
    var user;
    var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    userQuery.equalTo("username", phoneNumber);

    return userQuery
        .first(function(userResult){
            if(!helpers.isDefined(userResult)){
                userResult = createNewUser(phoneNumber);
            }else{
                userResult.set("smsVerified", false);
            }
            return userResult.save();
        })
        .then(function(userResult){
            user = userResult;
            return verification.createSmsVerification(user);
        })
        .then(function(){
            response.success();
        }, function (error){
            console.error("register - " + error.message);
            response.error(error.message);
        });
});

function createNewUser(phoneNumber){
    var newUser = new Parse.User();
    newUser.set("username", helpers.phoneToUsername(phoneNumber));
    newUser.set("password", helpers.generatePassword(phoneNumber));
    newUser.set("smsVerified", false);
    return newUser;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and I found that I'd hit the same error whenever I tried to call a function at the global level. The only time I've been able to call functions is within the scope of other functions.

Pertaining to your code, I imagine you're trying to export the function itself e.g.

```
exports.createSmsVerification = createSmsVerification;
```

The code you have:

```
exports.createSmsVerification = createSmsVerification();
```

actually calls the function and exports the result.

Comment: Yes this was basically the issue. It was the vague error message that had me stumped.

Comment: Yeah I've gotten quite a few unhelpful error messages from Parse. Their documentation on effectively modularizing cloud code isn't very good either, it's super hit or miss. It'd be nice to see more snippets and small/medium example projects.

Answer (score 1):

This took me about 3/4 of a day to find the answer. It is not in the documentation. The error is not clear at all.

The problem seems to be related to the way `export` is used. I assume that using `exports.methodName = methodName()` is trying to call the method, rather than set it as an attribute of `exports`. `exports.methodName = methodName` also works fine.

The following code **DOES NOT WORK**

```
function createSmsVerification(user) {
    return getUserSmsVerification(user)
        .then(function (verification) {
            var verificationQuery = new Parse.Query("Verification");
            return verificationQuery.first(); <-- this is the line causing the error
        })
        .then(function (verification) {
            return verification;
        }, function (error) {
            return Parse.Promise.error("createSmsVerification - " + error.message);
        });
}
exports.createSmsVerification = createSmsVerification();
```

The following code **DOES WORK**

```
exports.createSmsVerification = function(user) {
    return getUserSmsVerification(user)
        .then(function (verification) {
            var verificationQuery = new Parse.Query("Verification");
            return verificationQuery.first();
        })
        .then(function (verification) {
            return verification;
        }, function (error) {
            return Parse.Promise.error("createSmsVerification - " + error.message);
        });
}
```